# Flask SQLAlchemy: Getting record by id

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

What is the difference between the two below syntax:

```
post = Post.query.get(id)

post = Post.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
```

And which one i should use in something like updating or deleting a record? because i have tested booth syntax and they are working fine.

Booth code for deleting a record from db are bellow:

## The one with get()

```
@app.route("/post/<int:id>/delete", methods=["GET", "DELETE"])
def delete_post(id):
    post = Post.query.get(id)
    if not post:
        abort(404)
    db.session.delete(post)
    db.session.commit()
```

## The one with filter_by()

```
@app.route("/post/<int:id>/delete", methods=["GET", "DELETE"])
def delete_post(id):
    post = Post.query.filter_by(id=id).delete()
    if not post:
        abort(404)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Which one is more performant when want only to search against a model key? or are there the same in term of performance?

Answer (score 1):

`.get()`: You can use it filtering only model's primary keys [1](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/3ab2364e78641c4f0e4b6456afc2cbed39b0d0e6/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L818-L905).

`.first()`: You can use it filtering any model's column [2](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/3ab2364e78641c4f0e4b6456afc2cbed39b0d0e6/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L2706-L2730).

In both cases you will have only one result or `None`.

So, I recommend using it as follows: `post = Post.query.get(id)`

**EDIT**

The executed query for `get` is:

```
SELECT * FROM post
WHERE post.id = 1
```

The executed query for `first` is:

```
SELECT * FROM post
WHERE post.id = 1
LIMIT 1
```

`get` is faster because it doesn't run `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: I do know that .get() can only used to searches against a model primary key. the same thing can be done using filter_by().first(). but my question is more about which one is more performant? or are you thinking that when want to search against a model key .get() is more suited than filer_by()?

Comment: In your example, `get` is more performative because `first` would include the LIMIT clause in the query, and it's not needed

Comment: I was considering a two fields primary key, a making the query in only one of those fields. I edited it and I thought it best to remove it because it was very confusing